# Windows 7 x64 machine unresponsive after login

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze, clonezilla

My coworker's computer stopped working properly. After login the Desktop loads then everything slows to a snails pace. Meaning opening My Computer could take up to 5-10 minutes. Then seemingly randomly the computer just freezes and wont complete any task although the cursor moves freely.

I have gone through starting/stopping services on start-up but still can't pinpoint the problem. (I did this because in safe mode everything seems normal (in terms of speed) however some problems still exist). I want to re-image his computer since he has a clonezilla backup image however his outlook files have to backed up first. I cannot even do this since the copy gets hanged up on 96.2% (i used regular drag and drop as well as robocopy). the outlook file is roughly 8gb and there is 100gb of free space on the external HDD. I tried to copy in safe mode with the same results.

Any help or direction would b greatly appreciated... Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using Process Explorer to determine if a specific process is hogging resources?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: I checked and the cpu usage remains at 0% then jumps with any movement to screen to ~30% in terms of memory Physical is at 16% I am testing out process explorer now thanks

Comment: Yeah, hopefully it will tell you specifically which process is causing the resorurce spike. Unfortunately I have a sneaking suspicion that the culprit will be explorer.exe :)

Comment: That's what i concluded as well since its hogging 28k of memory. What would I do if that were the case? I am running out of options :( Thanks

Comment: In my experience (and this is purely anecdotal) file indexing is often the issue. I've never been faced with a situation that was bad enough that I figured out a good solution though, sorry.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the processes running (wont be too helpful but here it is anyways) [link](http://i1136.photobucket.com/albums/n489/maurycy407/screen.png) any ideas?

Comment: Can also be an infection...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add anything to the speed/performance  issue but  suggest removing the drive and attaching it directly to a working system to grab the data from Outlook. Either directly or with a USB adapter.

Comment: thanks :( that would be the last resort. I would have to go out and buy the usb adapter. Appreciated

Comment: A desktop system would allow you to conenct the problem drive even if you had to use the CD drive cables. Is it a laptop or a desktop system that has the issues? SATA or EIDE?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have a failing hard drive, or at least file-system corruption.

Any "NTFS" or "Disk" warning or failure entries in the Event Logs?

You should run a read-only disk check against it to see if it reports things are OK or not:

1. Open the "Computer" window.
2. Right-click on the drive in question.
3. Select the "Tools" tab.
4. In the Error-checking area, and click .
5. Un-check "Automatically fix file system error (to put it in Read-Only mode), and click .

Or open a command prompt and run `chkdsk c:`.

If it *does* report problems, you can then (re)run it in write-mode (check mark "automatically fix..." or run `chkdsk c: /f` and hopefully it will correct the problem enough tog et you working.

Keep in mind that chkdsk will just drop data in bad sectors, which can make things WORSE. :)   If bad sectors are suspected, consider obtaining and running [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm) (in recovery mode), before using chkdsk in write-mode, as SpinRite will attempt to determine what the data in a bad block was before marking it off-line.

Warning: If the drive is really messed up, both `chkdsk /F` and SpinRite could take *hours* to complete.

Comment: Thanks i actually already ran chkdsk and it made a bunch of changes ( i ran in read only since C: was being used by the system) it then ran in write mode on system reboot. I am now waiting/verifying if any fixes occurred. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes you have to do 2 chkdsk in a row to get it healed when it has more than a few problems with the file system. I had to do 3 in a row the other day on a really corrupt system.